# After function work global list changes too

Tags: python-3.x, list

Why, after *return matrix* is passed, *A* array in the global is changed if I passed a copy to function? I've tried
*create_matrix(A[:], B, 0); create_matrix(A.copy(), B, 0);* but in these cases the array A still changes, although I did not assign the result to the function like this
*A = create_matrix(A[:], B, 0)*. I think, the result of the function should just go to *print()*.

This is my code:

```
def create_matrix(matrix, matrix_B, num):
    for i in range(3):
        matrix[i][num] = matrix_B[i]  # example: matrix[0][0] = matrix_B[0]
    return matrix

A = [
    [4, -2, 1],
    [8, -1, 1],
    [1, 3, -1],
]
B = [
    -4,
    -2,
    6,
]

print(create_matrix(A[:], B, 0))
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[-4, -2, 1], [-2, -1, 1], [6, 3, -1]]  # After function
[[-4, -2, 1], [-2, -1, 1], [6, 3, -1]]  # A
```

*Here I want to replace values first column in A by values from B:  4 -> -4;  8 -> -2;  1 -> 6*

I want this output:

```
[[-4, -2, 1], [-2, -1, 1], [6, 3, -1]]  # After function
[[4, -2, 1], [8, -1, 1], [1, 3, -1]]  # A
```

Please tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that normal (shallow) copies in Python create a new memory location for the variable itself, but not its contents.  If the contents are immutable then in effect that shallow copy is independent of the original variable.  But, as in your case with a list of lists, if the contents are mutable then a shallow copy is not sufficient to provide the isolation you are seeking.  Instead, you will need to use `deepcopy` that copies both the variable and the contents of the variable to a new memory location.

Example:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy

print("** Example using copy.copy()")
global_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(f"Contents of global_list_of_lists: {global_list_of_lists}")
copy_of_global = copy(global_list_of_lists)
copy_of_global[0][0] = -1
print("Results after changing copy_of_global[0][0] to -1")
print(global_list_of_lists)
print(copy_of_global)

print("\n** Example using copy.deepcopy()")
global_list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(f"Contents of global_list_of_lists: {global_list_of_lists}")
copy_of_global = deepcopy(global_list_of_lists)
copy_of_global[0][0] = -1
print("Results after changing copy_of_global[0][0] to -1")
print(global_list_of_lists)
print(copy_of_global)
```

Output:

```
** Example using copy.copy()
Contents of global_list_of_lists: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Results after changing copy_of_global[0][0] to -1
[[-1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[-1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

** Example using copy.deepcopy()
Contents of global_list_of_lists: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
Results after changing copy_of_global[0][0] to -1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[-1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `numpy` package and you can get a copy of the input matrix Now if you change the value of the copy matrix, the value of the input matrix will not change.

```
import numpy as np
def create_matrix(matrix_A, matrix_B, num):
  matrix = np.copy(matrix_A)
  for i in range(3):
    matrix[i][num] = matrix_B[i]                 
  return matrix
```